# How to reduce RAM requirement in PETSC and SLEPCreading large binary matrices

Tags: petsc

I have two 50000 x 50000 binary matrices A and B for solving A*x=lambda*B*x eigenvalue problem. These matrices are sparse. I am trying to solve using PETSC and SLEPC. My memory requirement shoots off like more than 200 GB of RAM !

I used mpirun in 16 cores and 96GB RAM with swap of 130GB.

Is there a way to solve this problem.? Am I doing something wrong ?
Kindly let me know.

Comment: Please specify what algorithm you are using and `-log_summary` to show what the memory is being used for.  How sparse are the matrices?

Comment: It certainly appears that you're storing your matrices in a dense format with lots of working matrices, rather than using a sparse format, since a dense 50,000 by 50,000 double precision matrix would require only 8*50,000*50,000=20 gigabytes of RAM.